# How to notify a ViewModel when a new value is assigned to a member in another ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a WPF application that contains two ViewModels. I want to modify the value of a variable `Data` in ViewModel #1 and execute a function `Modify()` each time a new value is assigned to a variable `Id` in ViewModel #2. (I do not want to use a static member). Is there a solution using data binding in the View?

Assume that:

ViewModel #1:

```
class ViewModel1
{
    private double _id;
    public double Id 
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id= value; }
    }
}
```

ViewModel #2:

```
class ViewModel2
{
    private double data;
    public double Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data= value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does two ViewModels know about each other? If not you can use [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) to communicate between two ViewModels.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
What do you mean by "Does two ViewModels know about each other?"

Comment: I meant. Does `ViewModel1` has reference of `ViewModel2`. Does it contain any field or property for `ViewModel2`?

Comment: If it does , how can I make it works

Comment: If you have reference, you can call methods directly on it from the instance. See the posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case ViewModel #1 has reference of ViewModel #2, you can simply call methods from property ID setter.

```
class ViewModel1
{
    private ViewModel2 model2;

    private double _id;
    public double Id 
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
           _id= value;
           model2.Modify();           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact, the member Data of the ViewModel 2 is a list of Class A and it is "binding" to a ListView  in my View and the function "Modify" assign new value to Data for each call, But with this solution, I can not change the same member Data from the ViewModel 1?